# Check which coupon is used - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app that uses coupons. I want to know programmatically what is the coupon code that the user has entered and based on the input do the stuff.

For example, I have added manually to Cloud Firestore a code for signing up. How do I check in the app that this is the code used for signing up and the user has entered? And based on that coupon code do what should be done.

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzbnH.png)

Any help?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and show us how the coupon code looks like.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the coupon code from the user in a `EditText`
2. Get the coupon code from Firebase
3. Compare both with

   `String inputCode = editText.getText().toString();
   String cloudCode = task.getString("code");
   if (inputCode.equals(cloudCode)){
      //do your thing
   }`

here `task` is from `firebaseFirestore.collection().get();`

Edit 1:

Things to do before implementing Coupons

1. All coupon code should follow a Pattern
2. Pattern eg - `SALE0040` or `SIGN0050` or `DISC0020`
3. Patter like - `ABCD0123` or anything suits your needs
4. Your code will understand the type by looking at 1st half - `SIGN` and it will understand how much discount to give with 2nd half - `0050`

code -

```
String couponCode = task.getString("coupon");
String userCode = editText.getText().toString();
String type = couponCode.subString(0,4);
int discount = Integer.valueOf(couponCode.subString(4,couponCode.length()));
```

Same you can do with the user entered code
Now you have both values of both Coupons `Discount/Coupon type` and `Discount amount`

Comment: Yeah, I know that and I did it. But how can I let the code knows that this code which the user entered is, for example, the signup code?

Comment: Please explain a little bit more, do your app have other Coupons also? 
If yes, you need to have a format for your coupon-codes, eg- every code will have 8 char, 4 alphabets 4 digits, or something like this

Comment: Yes there will be other coupons and different ones.

Comment: ```substring()``` and ```size()``` are red text

Comment: replace `size()` with `length()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `EditText`, to get the code that is entered by the user you should use the following line of code:

```
String coupon = editText.getText().toString().trim();
```

Now having this `coupon` you can search the database to see if it actually exists, using the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference couponsRef = rootRef.collection("Coupons");
Query query = couponsRef.whereEqualTo("coupon", coupon);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

**Edit:**

If the code is only for `signup`, then you should add a new property under your coupon object named `type` and use the following query:

```
Query query = couponsRef.whereEqualTo("coupon", coupon).whereEqualTo("type", "signup");
```

Another way to solve this might be to get the name of the coupon and check if it starts with `SIGNUPCOUPON`.

Comment: This is to check if the coupon exists. But how can I let the code knows that this code which the user entered is, for example, the signup code?

Comment: Okay sorry for the misunderstanding from the first time. Maybe I should be more clear. Anyway, how does a shopping app works with coupons code? For example, the seller gives you a coupon for like 30%. How does the app's code check between all of the coupons available that this is for the 30%? In my case, it is the same. For now, there is only the signup coupon code. And it is not me who is going to create the coupons. The users are going to do it. So in the future, I want to make the code knows for what the coupon is.

Comment: You'll solve this using the solution from my edited answer. So you definitely should set the `type` of the coupon. It could be a `signup` coupon or a `30%` coupon, doesn't matter since you can query with it, right?

Comment: Okay but every time a user creates a coupon I should update the app's code?

Comment: I never heard about a system in which users can create coupons. Usually, the coupons are created by the owners and then provided to users. Image what will happen if each user creates a coupon with a 100% discount? :) If you want to let users create coupons, then you should constraint them to choose the type of the coupon so you can then query using it.

Comment: The word **user** used by the OP is referring the sellers for an example when a seller's adds his list of products into his application and creates an offer for all his listing. How can the buyer or customer can use a coupon filter to get results of all the products with that coupon usable.

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations I'm not sure I understand your question, but I recommend you post a new one, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I'm just trying to explain what user wants to convey in his question and I'm not trying to ask any question thanks for asking